# vb.net missing parameter passed to stored proc

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

The following code is generating the error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function
>   'usp_myStoredProc' expects parameter '@LineID', which was not
>   supplied.'

```
   Using cn As New   SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
       cn.Open()
       Using cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_myStoredProc", cn)
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineID", LineId)
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@dto1", SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset).Value = JamUpdateTimeCreated
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@dto2", SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset).Value = JamUpdateTimeCreated
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncludeZero", 0)
          Dim result = cmd.ExecuteReader
          Dim sections = new List(of Byte)
          While(result.Read)
            sections.Add(CType(result("Sect"), Byte))
          End While
          return sections
      End Using
   End Using
```

LineID is being set to LineID (which you can see in the image is 253)

[image]

You can see the debug from the image... ALl parameters are set.

The stored proc LineID expects a smallint
`dto1` and `dto2` are datetimeoffset

I've also tried `Add` and `AddWithValue` for each parameter, e.g.:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LineID", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = LineId
```

The stored proc

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_myStoredProc] 
@LineID SMALLINT,
@dto1 DATETIMEOFFSET,
@dto2 DATETIMEOFFSET,
@IncludeZero BIT = 0
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

when the command refers to a stored procedure.